Is it possible to have Git mark modified/delete conflict files more clearly?
In normal ("content") conflicts git will add conflict markers to the file, making it relatively clear where and what the issue is, and more importantly usually making it impossible not to resolve the conflict if there's any sort of CI/CD (as the conflict markers will very likely make the file invalid, and are easy to search for besides).
However a "modified/delete` conflict is not one of those. That is:

a branch B is forked off of A
a file is modified in branch A and deleted in B
A is merged in B

In that case, the file is essentially resurrected in B. It's marked as "DU", but in a big enough merge with enough conflicts it can be hard to notice, and because it's a resurrection the file is likely valid and not used by anything, so CI are likely to pretty much ignore it.
Obviously it's a user error, but is there a way to make Git surface this issue better / more clearly rather than discovering the resurrection days or weeks later, and tracing it back to an unfortunate conflict resolution?
I tried playing with conflict styles or searching around git-config but was not able to find anything relevant.
Full demo session:
$ git init -b A test
Initialized empty Git repository in test/.git/
$ cd test
$ echo "foo" > test.txt
$ git commit -amm
$ git add test.txt
$ git commit -amm
[A (root-commit) b1ed5e3] m
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt
$ git branch B
$ echo "bar" >| test.txt
$ git commit -amm
[A 02a53eb] m
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ git checkout B
Switched to branch 'B'
$ git rm test.txt
rm 'test.txt'
$ git commit -amm
[B 227d7f2] m
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
 delete mode 100644 test.txt
$ git merge --no-ff A
CONFLICT (modify/delete): test.txt deleted in HEAD and modified in A.  Version A of test.txt left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git status -sb
## B
DU test.txt
$ git add .
$ git status -sb
## B
A  test.txt
$ git commit -am "resolved"
[B 5d8a521] resolved
$ cat test.txt
bar


I'm not quite sure how you can fail to notice the situation, because if you don't resolve the merge conflict you will still be merging, and Git will tell you so, every single time you do just about anything and certainly when you ask for the status. If you have modified the terminal prompt as most heavy Git users do, it will tell you so every single time the terminal gives you a prompt (when you are in the project).

What is git ci? Evidently you have some pet aliases going on here. If you don't interpret for us, we can't reproduce your "demo session"...

@matt yeah sorry about that I didn't even notice them it's been so long, ci is just a shortcut for commit, and st is status -sb, I've edited the post to expand them.

@matt "I'm not quite sure how you can fail to notice the situation" by having to resolve tens to hundreds of conflicts and doing a git add on the wrong file (usually via some sort of UI). This is not the most major issue, but at $DAYJOB we've mitigated a lot of them via liberal applications of CI check. This one heuristics aside I'm not sure how to manage, and I've not found anything in the docs.

I still think the prompt in the Terminal is one of your best bets here. Mine, after enacting your scenario up to the prompt, says ~/Desktop/testinggit (git)-[B|merge]-. The merge is a dead giveaway. The other thing is that it sounds like your use of git status -sb is playing you false here; a full git status yells deleted by us: test.txt. So my suggestion is: (1) a better prompt line; (2) a fuller git status output; and (3) don't say git add . — that is exactly how unwanted files sneak into a commit. Luckily we usually catch them during pull request. Usually. :)

Also maybe you could add more colorization and/or text styling to your git status output, though Git does not make all the distinctions here that one might have hoped.

I'm pretty sure the only reason I don't have this same problem is that for any substantial merge conflict resolution, I use a UI tool which stages each resolved file individually as I go ("accept merge" or similar). If that wasn't the case I could see myself wanting to use git add . to quickly stage them all after resolution. But even then you still may want to do them individually so you can tell from git status which ones are already resolved. Otherwise it feels like too much to remember. My point here is git add . should probably just be avoided during conflict resolution...

If you use my git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3 script it will explicitly ask you if you want to add or remove such files. Bonus: it will launch a proper 3-way merge tool for resolving both modified conflicts.
